# android:pathPattern has no effect on intent-filter behavior

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'd like to make my filter to pass only `*.pls` files. According the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html it should be working (I think) but it's not. Instead of the expected behavior (passing `.pls` files only) all file types are being passed.

```
<intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pls" />

</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-read the docs you'll notice this line relating to the `android:path`, `android:pathPrefix`, and `android:pathPattern`

> These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes
>   are also specified for the filter.

You are missing the `android:host` atttribute. Add

```
<data android:host="*" />
```

to your intent-filter as the docs specify

Comment: This does not work when host=(null) as is the case when opening from Google Drive; it causes the file type to not be recognized. Does anyone have another answer?

Comment: From Google drive, I guess the scheme is not file but content (it uses a ContentProvider I guess)